# How to publish C# project with SQL database

Tags: c#, .net

I am quite new in programming, I managed to make a programme in Visual Studio 2013, with an SQL DB. I published the project well, and even copied the DB to the bin/debug file. All is well but my programme cannot connect to the DB, is there a step am missing during publishing?

Comment: How are you getting connected to your database ?

Comment: what is the connection error? File not found, missing permissions...etc?

Comment: does the SQL Server instance exist? what is your connection string? are you using SQLExpress?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, am not using sql express, in visual studio it works fine but i cannot access the db to log in a different machine

Answer (score 0):

Keep Database in App_Data folder and follow following step than you can use following approach:

> 

```
<add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Book.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: in visual studio, my programme runs very well, but after i publish it, and try to install to another computer, the programme cannot connect to the database, even thought the a copy of the database is in the bin/debug file

Comment: Is SQL Server installed on your another pc

Comment: HI Pavan, yes the sql is installed in another pc